# How to adjust the x axes in a multiplot to have the same length

Tags: plot, gnuplot, axes

I basically want to have share the x axis in three plots in a multiplot.

Here is the code:

```
set terminal wxt enhanced size 480,288 dashed;
#Header end
set multiplot;
set size 1,0.4;
set origin 0,0;
set xlabel "x";
set ylabel "y1";
set ytics 200;
set key off;
plot '-' u 1:2:xtic(3) w points, '-' w points;
1 851 1
2 663 4
3 367 8
4 368 9
e
1 829 1
2 646 4
3 354 8
4 359 9
e
set xlabel "";
set format x "";
set size 1,0.3;
set origin 0,0.4;
set ylabel "y2";
set ytics 0.6;
plot '-'  w points, '-' w points;
1 1.633468456
2 1.113943352
3 1.361727836
4 1.643452676
e
1 1.447158031
2 1.380211242
3 1.414973348
4 1.643452676
e
set size 1,0.3;
set origin 0,0.7;
set ylabel "y3";
set ytics 1000;
plot '-' w points, '-' w points;
1 3317
2 1567
3 846
4 895
e
1 3342
2 1612
3 978
4 1101
e
unset multiplot
```

Here is the current figure:

[image: plot, x axes different lengths]

I want to adjust the x axes in this multiplot to have the same length, so that the three plots can share the x axis.

---

Update:

After adding "set lmargin at screen 0.2;" in the beginning of the code, I have the following:

[image: plot, x axes same length]

It is close to what I want but the three y labels are not aligned anymore: y2 is not in line with y1 and y3. How can I ensure that the labels are aligned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved simply by explicitly setting the left margin. The right one is aligned by default.

By adding `set lmargin at screen 0.1`, you can obtain the following:

[image: plots with equal left margins]

You can also tweak the top and bottom margins of each plot if you like, to join together the plots like this:

[image: plots joined together by adjusting top and bottom margins]

To achieve this I used `set bmargin 0.05; set tmargin 0.35` for the first plot, then `set bmargin 0.35` for the second, etc. I also adjusted the `yrange` to prevent the `ytics` from overlapping too much. Adjust to taste! :)

---

As you've pointed out, the `lmargin` value also affects the positioning of the `ylabel`. To deal with this, you have a few options:

1. Use something like `set format y "%.1e"` to ensure that the format is consistent for each graph. By enforcing a fixed number of decimal places, the `ylabel`s will all be aligned.
2. Use `set ylabel offset` to shift the labels into place. Don't forget that the offset will be applied to all subsequent `ylabel`s, so if you want to shift the middle one but not the last, you need to explicitly reset the offset to `0` on the last one.
3. Instead of using `ylabel` at all, just use `set label at screen X,Y rotate by 90`, where `X` is fixed and `Y` is will differ for each plot. This gives you maximum flexibility over the positioning of the labels.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but after using "set lmargin at screen 0.2;" the three y labels are not aligned anymore. Please see my second figure.

Comment: There are some ways you can get around this problem. I have added some suggestions to my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: If you use `set ylabel offset` you must specify a value in all three cases: `set ylabel 'y1'; ...; set ylabel 'y2' offset -1; ...; set ylabel 'y3' offset 0`. Otherwise the last label would retain the changed offset of the previous set.